# Add user capability and check against it

Tags: capabilities, user-access, users

I just realized the following:

```
// Call the current user info
global $current_user;

// Add a capability
// and set the 2nd argument ($grant) to false
$current_user->add_cap( 'some_cap', false );
```

Now I've successfully added a capability to the user, but denied her/him the access to this capability.

If I now check with `$current_user->has_cap( 'some_cap' );` I'd get a `true` in return. The same goes for `current_user_can( 'some_cap' );` as this is only a wrapper for the has_cap functions arguments.

**Q:** Where is the 2nd argument used? Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using it right. I think it is actually a bug in WordPress.

When you do the same for roles `$somerole->add_cap( 'some_cap', false );`, it works as expected.